# Docker image not copying files names starting with

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-build

I have a node app which has a file named ".env" which has all my configuration properties. The docker build command is successful but the file is missing from the docker image. I don't have a ".dockerignore" file in my folder.

Also, another app with the same boilerplate works fine and the ".env" file is copied in the docker image. Any ideas?

> FROM node:8-alpine
>
> EXPOSE 3000
>
> ARG NODE_ENV ENV NODE_ENV $NODE_ENV
>
> RUN mkdir /app WORKDIR /app ADD package.json yarn.lock /app/ RUN yarn
>   --pure-lockfile ADD . /app
>
> CMD ["yarn", "docker:start"]

Comment: Can you post the Dockerfile (or at least a part of it, with the commands that copy files to the container). Note that files starting with "." are not normally matched by the ? and \* wildcards, so if you have something like COPY * /target_dir, this will not copy ".env".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work. The problem was my .env file was added to my .gitignore file(which was missing from my other service) and when I removed it worked. Weird!